# Cryptic Family Reunion: Don't Drink the Blue Koolaid

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". I hope you enjoy!

1. Rapper sounding like Twisted Sister (7)
2. Thrown from bucking equine, I am dizzy the day before presenting daughter (5,5)
3. Uncle Winslow bags antelope (10)
4. Niece's biting critique about abstract art (9)
5. Smashing tiara over nutbrown wig becomes wife (1-5)
6. Trouble in unsettled realm leads to brother (11)
7. Aunt Robin is confused about deficit (5,4)
8. Dad to mail distributor cap housing back: flaw with blown head (7)
9. Heed spasms in escalating stroke indication for Grandpa (3,4)
10. Aunt Ann's clutter being organized (11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> These are *The Boys* characters.

> 1. EZE("Eazy-E") KIEL*

> 2. QUEEN(-I)* MA* EVE

> 3. HOM(ELAND)ER

> 4. S(TAR*)LIGHT

> 5. ATRAI* N_

> 6. LAM(PLIGHT)ER*

> 7. B(LACK)NOIR* (solved by [El-Guest](/users/50778/el-guest))

> 8. P.O. P_C< _LAW (with thanks to El-Guest for pointers in this direction)

> 9. T(HEDE*)EP<

> 10. TRANSLUCENT*

Comment: 8 is rot13(CBCPYNJ) — rot13(znvy qvfgevohgbe (CBC) + (P)nc + synj jvgu oybja urnq (SYNJ - S = YNJ)).

Comment: @El-Guest not quite. I've edited. Thanks!

Comment: nice! I just figured out the theme, and came back to the question to start writing up my answer, and then... -_- good job :)

Comment: thanks @kristinalustig

Comment: Nice job! Almost there...there was no error in #7, so your answer is not correct, but I do like what you did there. The category is a bit more specific than what you've posited, which might help explain #7 a bit better. Re #1: remember that I'm pretty old, so when I say "rapper", think 1990s.

Comment: 7 is actually rot13(OYNPX ABVE — EBOVA* = O_____ABVE + qrsvpvg (YNPX)) should do the trick.

Comment: I think the category is specifically rot13(_fhcreurebrf_ sebz _Gur Oblf_) instead.

Comment: @JeremyDover thanks, I think I got the rapper now.